# How to update date in table based on two criteria from a select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a date in one table based on if an userID and planName are returned from a select off a different table.
Something like

```
UPDATE Table A
SET DATE = GETDATE()
WHERE userid AND planName IN (SELECT userid, planName From Table B)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to join these two tables in an `UPDATE` statement.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE [Table A] 
SET DATE = GETDATE()
FROM [Table A] a
INNER JOIN [Table B] b on a.userid = b.userid and a.planName = b.planName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
UPDATE A
  SET
      A.DATE = GETDATE()
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB AS B
    WHERE B.userid = A.userid
          AND B.planName = A.planName
);
```

this will update all the rows in your table A that have the exact combination(s) of userid and planName that exist in table B

so if Table A has the following:

```
userid planName 
1       A
2       A
1       B
```

and Table B has the following

```
userid planName 
1       A 
1       B
```

it will only update the following in Table A:

```
userid planName 
1       A 
1       B
```

Comment: I have two rows in my inner select but when I go to update table A it is updating every row.

Comment: if you run this how many rows does it return: SELECT A.*
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB AS B
    WHERE B.userid = A.userid
          AND B.planName = A.planName
);

Comment: That returns all of table A. What I'm trying to do is update Table A if I get a userid and plan name returned from a separate Select

Comment: so check your table B the reason might be that the all the combination(s) of userid and planName in table A exist in table B

Comment: They do. Table B feeds into Table A. We use table A to create a .CSV and there are outliers where the dates in the database need to be updated if they meet a certain criteria.

Comment: so then the     WHERE B.userid = A.userid  AND B.planName = A.planName needs to reflect that. you might be missing a condition here use the select statement in my previous comments to test your query before running the update

Comment: I'm able to get the two rows from Table B that I would want to get back, I'm trying to figure out how to update only those two rows in Table A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148553/discussion-between-kamran-farzami-and-troy-r).

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps...

```
-- some test data...
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableA', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TableA;

CREATE TABLE #TableA (
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    PlanName VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    SomeDate DATE NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID)
    );

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableB', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TableB;

CREATE TABLE #TableB (
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    PlanName VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID, PlanName)
    );

INSERT #TableA (UserID, PlanName) VALUES
    (1, 'aaa'), (2, 'aab'), (3, 'abb'),
    (4, 'aaa'), (5, 'aab'), (6, 'ccc');

INSERT #TableB (UserID, PlanName) VALUES
    (1, 'aaa'), (1, 'abb'), (1, 'bbb'),
    (2, 'aaa'), (2, 'abb'), (2, 'bbb'),
    (3, 'aaa'), (3, 'abb'), (3, 'bbb'),
    (4, 'aaa'), (4, 'abb'), (4, 'bbb'),
    (5, 'aaa'), (5, 'abb'), (5, 'bbb'),
    (6, 'aaa'), (6, 'abb'), (6, 'bbb');

--=========================================

-- check initial values...
SELECT * FROM #TableA ta;
SELECT * FROM #TableB tb;

-- written as a SELECT...
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    #TableA ta
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TableB tb WHERE ta.UserID = tb.UserID AND ta.PlanName = tb.PlanName);

    -- written as an UPDATE...
UPDATE ta SET 
    ta.SomeDate = GETDATE()
FROM
    #TableA ta
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TableB tb WHERE ta.UserID = tb.UserID AND ta.PlanName = tb.PlanName);

-- check updated values...
SELECT * FROM #TableA ta;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was able to get it:

```
WITH CTE (userid, planName)
AS (SELECT userid, planName From Table B) 
UPDATE A
SET DATE = GETDATE()
FROM Table A
JOIN CTE B
ON B.userid = A.userid AND B.planName = A.planName
```

Comment: This is effectively what I answered, sans the CTE. While there is no difference between our queries in terms of updating the correct records, the CTE seems to be a longer query; slightly wordier.